# Is it possible to pin a Flexible Header in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, material-components

I'm writing an app in iOS and using the Material Components Cocoapod. I'm using a flexible header and would like to be able to "pin" it, much like the Android version of a flexible header. An Android flexible header seems to hit a critical point and then transition to either the expanded or collapsed state depending on the scroll direction. Whereas on iOS the MDC Flexible Header tracks the scroll view very well, but you can have points of an intermediate scroll with the header half way between the terminal points.

I'd like to have behavior like the Android version on my iOS app. Is there a way to accomplish this with the library? Or should I create logic to set the header height based on the scroll position?

Any thoughts/help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should search for `swift sticky table header`, it will find you some great resources and tutorials on the topic, like this one: http://sweettutos.com/2016/09/14/how-to-implement-a-sticky-view-while-table-view-scrolls-like-app-store-app-swift-3/

Comment: Good article but unfortunately I have to use the flexible header as s requirement for the project I'm working on. This is the one out of the box in the Google MDC cocoapod I'm referring to.